# BizTalk POP3 adapter security

Tags: biztalk, pop3, exchange-server-2010, biztalk-2013

In BizTalk, I am looking for a way to avoid supplying the password in the Bindings of receive locations that uses the POP3 Adapter to connect to an Exchange Server.

On other adapters like FTP this is possible to supply a password via the SSO, it seems that using the SSO is is not an option on the POP3 adapter?

On MSDN it is described that "[Secure Password Authentication (SPA). The POP3 server uses current process credentials for authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546737.aspx)". So I have tried to give the Service Account running the Host Instance access to the mailbox, but without success.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: When I give the Service Account access to the Mail Box and removes the password for the mailbox user I get an authentication error.

Comment: Yes, there is no SSO Affiliate Application setting for POP3 (as per my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155838/how-can-i-set-sb-messaging-adapter-credentials-securely/37174322#37174322).  Did you get any further in resolving this problem?